# firebase cloud function function looping in execution

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to make a resume of the existing data but Firebase cloud function does the looping so that the summation I made is not valid. is there a solution to my problem?
thank you

this in my screen shoot

database construction
[image],

log
[image]

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var db = admin.database();
exports.makePurchaseSummaryAdd = functions.database.ref('/invoice_data/{pushIdInvoice}/item/{pushIdItem}')
    .onCreate(event => {
        var name = event.data.child('itemName').val();
        var quantity = event.data.child('quantity').val();

        var ref = db.ref('/invoice_data/' + event.params.pushIdInvoice + '/idUser');
        ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
            var refUser = db.ref('/user_data/' + snapshot.val() + '/purchaseSummary/' + name.toUpperCase());
            refUser.on("value", function(snapshotUser) {
                if (snapshotUser.exists()){
                    console.log('Ada Data');
                    var count = snapshotUser.val();
                    var newCount = quantity + count;
                    refUser.set(newCount);
                    console.log('create', count, newCount, name.toUpperCase());
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Tidak Ada Data');
                }
            }, function (errorObject) {
              console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
            });
        }, function (errorObject) {
          console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        });
        return true;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attaching database reference listeners using the [on()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#on) method.  This leaves the listener attached:

> Your callback will be triggered for the initial data and again
>   whenever the data changes

You should instead use [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once):

> Listens for exactly one event of the specified event type, and then
>   stops listening

Your code is looping because you attach a listener `refUser.on(...)`  and then are changing the value at that location in the callback: `refUser.set(newCount);`