# firebase get parrent of parent data before delete

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I try to using this code but not working

```
var idUser = event.data.ref.parent.ref.parent.child('idUser').previous.val();
```

then I get an error when try using

```
event.data.ref.parent.ref.parent.child('idUser').onDelete(event => {
    event.data.previous.val();
});
```

This is my full code

```
exports.makePurchaseSummaryDelete = functions.database.ref('/invoice_data/{pushIdInvoice}/item/{pushIdItem}')
    .onDelete(event => {
    var name = event.data.child('itemName').previous.val();
    var quantity = event.data.child('quantity').previous.val();
    var idUser = event.data.ref.parent.ref.parent.child('idUser').previous.val();
    var refUser = db.ref('/user_data/' + idUser + '/purchaseSummary/' + name.toUpperCase());
    refUser.once("value", function(snapshotUser) {

    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });

    return true;
});
```

[image: database structure]

Comment: I can not see the picture

Comment: @Hari: There is no Firebase Cloud Functions tag. Please see the tag [change I made](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45491967/revisions), since I made it to your previous question too. See my explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854865/what-is-the-difference-between-cloud-function-and-firebase-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database events are automatically passed any data for the node the event triggered (and downwards).

When you go up the `parent` chain, you will have to explicitly load the data by attaching a listener. That's quite similar to what you already did in your question here: [firebase cloud function function looping in execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45475686/firebase-cloud-function-function-looping-in-execution)

That unfortunately means that you cannot get the previous value for nodes higher in the hierarchy than where you triggered the function.

Comment: thanks for your answer, can i get previous data before delete from snapshot?

Comment: Not from a regular `Snapshot`. The previous value is only available in a `DeltaSnapshot`. You can only get a `DeltaSnapshot` from the `event` parameter. Anything from a listener is a regular `Snapshot`.