# Cloud Functions for Firebase: How do I trigger a database function for a specific child key of all children

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Let's say my database looks like the following:

```
project
└── users
    ├── safuhf8sdf76fs
    │   ├── name: 'William'
    │   └── favoriteColor: 'blue'
    ├── sffuef5srf72fd
    │   ├── name: 'Emily'
    │   └── favoriteColor: 'yellow'
    └── rfdu4ffsgf42gi
        ├── name: 'Sam'
        └── favoriteColor: 'red'
```

I'm trying to create a Cloud Function that is triggered when the `favoriteColor` value of any `user` object is changed/added/removed.

The part I'm having trouble with is creating the reference to said key.

I know that I could listen to any and all changes to users with

`exports.updatedFavoriteColor = functions.database.ref('/users').onWrite(event => { ... });`

and then just check the data changed to see if it was `favoriteColor`.

While this would work, I'd much prefer a trigger that is **specifically** listening for the `favoriteColor` key of all user objects- something kind of like this: `functions.database.ref('/users').child(?).child('favoriteColor')`

My preferable function would be called when the `favoriteColor` of William or Emily is changed, but not when the `name` of Sam is changed, for example. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out with some more digging.

The [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data) suggest I can do the following:

```
exports.updatedFavoriteColor = functions.database.ref('/users/{pushId}/favoriteColor').onWrite(event => { ... });
```

This should get triggered by the change in `favoriteColor` for any user, where the particular user being updated is represented by the `{pushId}` in the reference. In the function itself, you can reference the user id with `event.params.pushId`

Comment: *firebaser here* That's indeed the way to do it. Little note: the `event.data` in this case will only contain the previous and new value of `favoriteColor`. If you need the entire user node, you'll have to load it separately. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45491967/firebase-get-parrent-of-parent-data-before-delete/45492805#45492805